# maven repository and dependencies download

Tags: maven-2

I've used standard maven command `mvn clean install` and according to logs (in the same console window) dependencies were loaded and artifacts were installed to my dedicated directory for maven repository `P:\.m2\repository`. Maven build process succeeded.
I'm using maven 2.2.1

Here is the problem. Repository directory is empty. What I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some reasons:

1. Someone deleted the folder (or it's content)
2. Maven installed the files in a different place

I suggest to run `mvn` again with the option `-X`. Running `mvn clean -X` should be enough to see the paths which it uses to locate dependencies (`install` will download many more files but we need to see only one).

Note: `P:\` sounds like a network drive. Even if this is your home folder (i.e. not shared with other people), this isn't a very good idea since it will cause a lot of network traffic and make your builds slow and brittle (in case of network problems).

Comment: here is snippent from maven build log [INFO] Installing C:\dev\XXX.jar to P\.m2\repository\XXX.jar

Comment: There is typo in the path...  Thanks for the hint. It is weird maven didn't report any problem.

Comment: Why should it? `P\...` is a valid relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the repository location in your m2_install_dir/conf/settings.xml?
If not, try to locate your files in something like: 
C:\Documents & Settings\your_username.m2
or C:\Users\your_username.m2

Comment: i've removed mave settings.xml from maven installation folder, my ${user.home}/.m2 contains settings.xml and repository explicitly set to    <localRepository>P\.m2\repository </localRepository> there

Comment: Probably would be better if you restore your settings.xml in m2_home/conf and will change repository location inside it

Comment: there is my domain password there used in proxy configuration. Home directory at least is not shared for all users

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using something like gitbash and its stripping off the backslashes in your repo value. run maven install with -X. check if you have a directory called P:\.m2repository

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted your `.m2/` folder and need to recreate it, ensure you assign the proper permissions.

```bash
chmod -R 755 ~/.m2
```